# Collect custom data from every connected client

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, client-server, multiplayer

In my MMORPG project from scratch, i'm currently stuck in getting the actual positions (x,y,z) of nearby online players to the place where a new character is about to login so he sees them in their right positions. 
I have a variable that keeps track of the player's position, but i need to get all the nearby players without requesting the position from the client cuz as i said i have it stored in a variable.
Further explanation: A new player logged in and he's about to spawn. Near him there is 5 other players already logged in, so he should see them as soon as he spawn. On my multithreaded server code i have variable to keep updated position.

> How can i implement that variable to get every connected client
>   position or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**The Foundation:**

You are going to want to define a global update interval like 100ms, so that all clients remain in sync. Then you are going to want to use the UDP protocol to transmit their positions between the client and server. UDP is crucial to games as it is much faster, and TCP in this case will take too long.

**Using UDP:**
UDP is not hard to work with in C#. You establish a target server and the server establish a incoming port and then you can start accepting incoming and sending outgoing traffic. You will have to devise a way to remember which packet is for which player, but that is easy as long as you add to each UDP packet a unique tag. A beautiful explanation to getting started with UDP can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/simple-udp-example-code?forum=netfxnetcom).